# How to implement search with hit highlight in Universal Viewer

Tags: manifest.json, iiif

I have converted PDF files to JP2 images and showing them in Universal Viewer.
Now, I want to implement search with hit highlight and autocomplete in Universal Viewer.
One of the way I have found that I have to create annotations for it.
I want the search functionality to work on all the texts inside.
But, I am not being able to find a way to generate the annotations dynamically for all the texts.
Please let me know how I can generate annotations dynamically for all the texts with positions from manifest.json.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The texts to search and highlight are not defined in the manifest.json, that is designed only for the metadata and that is managed by [IIIF Presentation API](https://iiif.io/api/presentation/3.0).

The search is managed via the [IIIF Content Search API](https://iiif.io/api/search/1.0), that is another endpoint that you indicate as a service inside the manifest.json. In this second endpoint, you can add a process to convert results to the query into zones to highlight from a prepared text (generally an xml extracted from ocr).